# How to name a range on a future dynamically created sheet using a macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to know if it is possible to use a macro to name a range on a sheet that does not exist yet, but will in the future.

In the instance I am trying to use this in, the future spreadsheets are dynamically created using a `Worksheet_Change` event where the name of the new sheet is typed into a list. (I can include the macro used for this if it is relevant)

I have already looked into a couple of ideas:

I have tried using `=Indirect` as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079169/is-it-possible-to-name-a-range-on-a-sheet-that-does-not-exist-yet) on StackOverflow.
The worksheet name was populated into A2 and the cell required was in B30 on the new page: `=INDIRECT("'"&$A2&"'!"&B30))`
However, this did not work because:
As the worksheet could be named anything, this solution uses an absolute reference, rather than a relative reference. A relative reference is preferred as the referenced cell could move up or down with inserted/deleted rows.

I have also tried using a macro to define a named range. The following macro works when the sheet name is defined (In this case, on the "Master" sheet). It finds a cell value and names the single-cell range 6 cells to the right as "Total"+Sheetname (In this case, "TotalMaster").
The part that I am stumped at is how to refer to the future sheets in the macro. This is further complicated by the fact that there could be any number of new sheets made. I would also like to be able to dynamically name the range as `"Total"+Sheetname`

```
Sub MakeName()
Dim Sht As String

Sht = ActiveSheet.Name

  Sheets("Master").Range("A1").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="TOTAL MD (RES)", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False).Activate
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Select
  ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Total" & Sht, RefersTo:=Selection

End Sub
```

To summarise my question:

1. How can I edit my macro to name a range on a future page? I guess this could be incorporated into a `worksheet_change` event so that when a new sheetname is added to the sheets list, the macro runs on the new page?
2. How can I edit these sections of code to refer to the newly created sheet, rather than the active sheet?
   `Sht = ActiveSheet.Name` & `ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Total" & Sht`

Comment: ` Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
        Range("C3").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=ActiveSheet.Name & "rngName", RefersTo:=Selection
    
    End Sub `

Answer (score 1):

Use the Workbook_NewSheet event. Some care should be taken to make sure that the code isn't triggered if a chart sheet (as opposed to a work sheet) is added. Something like:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    On Error GoTo ignore_me
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sh
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Total" & ws.Name, RefersTo:=ws.Range("A1")
    Exit Sub
ignore_me:
    'must be a chart sheet added -- take no action
End Sub
```

Comment: ++ Good Point about the charts :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.Type <> -4167 Then Exit Sub

    Dim aCell As Range, rng As Range

    Set aCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Cells.Find(What:="TOTAL MD (RES)", _
                                                         LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                                         LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                                         SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                                         MatchCase:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then Set rng = aCell.Offset(, 6)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then _
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Total" & Sh.Name, RefersTo:=rng
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This almost seems to do what I need it to. When you do the find function, does this code search only the "master" sheet? What I meant was to apply the find to the new sheet.

Comment: Yes because that is what you did in the original code. If you need to find in the new sheet then replace `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")` with `Sh`

Comment: This code seems like it should work. However both this code and the code submitted by John Coleman don't work in my workbook. It works when I click the "add new sheet" button next to the sheet tabs but in this workbook, new sheets are added by copying a master sheet. Should this code still work for when a new sheet is created by copying?

Comment: @yaz1069 You seem to have stumbled upon a gap in Excel VBA's built-in event handlers. There doesn't seem to be any CopySheet event. See this question for discussion of work-arounds: http://stackoverflow.com/q/722409/4996248 .

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks for that information. I looked into the other link and have managed to solve this issue with a workaround. I kept the `MakeName()` code and called it in the sheet generating `worksheet_change` code with a call function: `Call MakeName()`